# I have opened a program from a website, has my MBP been infected with a virus?

Tags: mac, anti-virus

I have opened a file on https://kickass.so/revenge-s04e14-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t10127520.html. I was supposed to click on a torrent file but I clicked on the big DOWNLOAD link.

And I had no idea that  I was not supposed to open a dmg file. Anyway, done is done. I opened it, and there was an install file, I double clicked on it. Then I was not asked to do anything, it just directed me to a website.

How do I make sure I do not have a virus or spyware? Running AIR'13 Yosemite.
The file name was `macfest`. The content looks like this:
[image]

I also used Sophos Anti-virus and it detected `OSX/FkCodec-A` in the dmg file that I trashed.

Comment: What was the file name of the DMG, the installer and what was the domain you got directed to? You probably don't have a virus if the installer you opened didn't ask for a password.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. The filename is macfest and the content is shown in the quest.

Comment: It looks like it will set your homepage and install an extension. Both can be checked from preferences (system preferences and browser-specific preferences). Extensions might also end up in the internet plug-ins directory which resides in the library directory (home and/or system wide).